# Redundant similar indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm cleaning up a database (SQL Server 2012) that has lots of indexes. Some, I believe, could be deleted or merged.

For example, I have there is *index1* :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [index1] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Project] ASC
)
INCLUDE (a_bunch_of _columns)
```

and *index2* :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [index2] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [Project] ASC,
    [Type] ASC
)
INCLUDE (a_bunch_of _columns)
```

I see in the DB statistics that *index1* is used much more than *index2* but I believe that all the info in *index1* can be found into *index2*. So if a delete *index1*, the DB engine would seek into *index2* instead of *index1* how it does now. The performance shoud be as good as now. (even a bit better since there would be one less index to maintain)

Is that correct or I am missing something ?

Comment: Presuming the include columns in `index1` are all in `index2` then your assumption is correct. You may need to clear the plan cache for some of your procedures that make use of the old index using `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE` also.

Comment: Got to BrentOzar.com and look at their query sp_BlitzIndex, that'll highlight a lot of the duplicates or near duplicates while also showing you missing indexes that may be of advantage to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that "a_bunch_of_columns" is the same (or that the columns for the second are a superset of the first), then you are correct.

The only advantage to the first index is that it occupies less space in memory.  However, that is a really, really negligible advantage compared to removing the index altogether.

Comment: Totally agree, the other thing to note is that if both indexes are used (even only a little) then they're both going to be held in memory anyway.